# Phabricator Wiki (Phriction) page without menus

Tags: phabricator

We want to create a "what's new" page in Phriction, as we can seamlessly link with the issues and other help articles.

However, we also want to display this web page in our Qt application (when it detects a new version is available for download). But in that particular case it would be nice to just have a plain vanilla page without all phabricator menus etc.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could link to the print version of the page, or build your own page via conduit. There are no "skins" for Phriction.

Comment: I can see there is a print version which seems to be usable. Good idea, however, is there an URL parameter to explicitly call the print version?

Comment: Where did you look for the URL? I'd hope it's pretty obvious if you already use Phabricator. Click on Actions then "Printable Page"

Comment: I have just used CTRL+P, but this is much better. Also I do not see Actions on all of these pages, however `__print__=1` seems to do the trick. Thanks!