# Phabricator Phane Blog in Qt HTML view

Tags: qt, phabricator

I want to display a Phabricator (Phame) blog in an Qt HTML edit (e.g. `QTextEdit`). In general no problem, but I wonder if there is a way to get rid of all the menus and such.

Can I somehow call a Phame list in print mode, maybe this will do the trick. I have checked Conduit, but there seems to be no API function for that.

Any better ideas (to obtain a plain vanilla list of the BLOG entries)?

Comment: What do you mean by HTML edit? And if you just want blog entry titles, is there an RSS feed available?

Comment: E.g. QTextEdit via setHtml, and unfortunately there is no RSS feed (or I am not aware of it, but I have checked the Conduit API)

Answer (score 0):

With an older post of mine I have found a hint how to [force the print mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44738613/356726). At least something, less unwanted menus. Not optimal yet as still some headers / footers are still displayed.

Example: `https://blog.xyz.net/?__print__=1`